# Consulta sobre insercion de caracter en un array de caracteres

Tags: array, c

Hice el siguiente codigo para insertar un caracter en un array ordenado alfabeticamente.

```
char abecedario [] = {"abcdefg"}; /*El array con los caracteres*/
    int vAbecedario = 8; /* Son los elementos validos que tiene el array*/
    char dato = 'x' ;    /*El dato que deseo insertar pero que no se encuentra en el array*/
```

```
int insertarCharOrdenado (char a [], int validos, char dato)
{
    int i = validos - 1;
    while (i>=0 && a[i] != dato)
    {
        a[i+1]=a[i];
        i--;
    }
        a[i+1]= dato;

    return validos +1;
}
```

Pero si el elemento no esta en el array lo posiciona igualemente al principio de este y me gustaria que no lo haga, como puede generar una condicion para esto? En este caso me pone x al principio del array

Comment: No entendi, puede editar la pregunta y colocar un ejemplo del array los datos validos y el caracter a insertar y cual sería el resultado esperado

Comment: Ya la edite, a ver si es mas claro.

Comment: osea que debe quedar `abcdefgx` de acuerdo a que esta en orden alfabetico?

Comment: Tu condición del bucle no es correcta para lo que quieres. Solo compruebas no salirte del array, y que el carácter de ese momento sea distinto del buscado. La condición de mantenerte debe ser que el dato sea INFERIOR al valor del carácter actual.

Comment: @Jakala Claramente me funciono cambiando el != por un >. Pero si hago esto y pongo a la funcion le paso un dato que SI este en el array la misma no me lo inserta

Comment: Bueno, tampoco indicabas que querías que de insertará si había un duplicado. Prueba con >=

Answer (score 0):

```
int insertarCharOrdenado (char a [], int validos, char dato) 
{
    int i = validos - 1; 
    while (i>=0 && a[i] > dato) 
    {
        a[i+1]=a[i];                
        i--;                        
    }
        a[i+1]= dato;               

    return validos +1;              
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema se divide en dos partes:

1. Localizar punto de inserción.
2. Insertar.

---

#### Localizar punto de inserción.

Para localizar el punto de inserción y asumiendo que quieres un orden alfabético, tan sólo debes recorrer la formación<sup>1</sup> y comparar cada elemento con el elemento a insertar, deberás parar el bucle cuando el elemento a insertar deje de ser mayor al elemento en la posición actual:

```
char *c = abecedario;
char *fin = abecedario + sizeof(abecedario);
for (; dato > *c && c != fin; ++c);
```

Fíjate que el bucle no tiene cuerpo, sólo lo usamos para avanzar el puntero de escritura, al finalizar el bucle `c` apuntará al punto de inserción, te pongo ejemplos con dos elementos:

```
| 0 | 1 |
|---+---|
| e | i |
```

- Si insertamos `'a'`, dado que no es mayor que `'e'`, el bucle no llega a dar ninguna vuelta, el punto de inserción es `0`.
- Si insertamos `'g'`, sabemos que es mayor que `'e'` por lo que el bucle da una vuelta, en la segunda vuelta sabemos que no es mayor que `'i'`, el punto de inserción es `1`.
- Si insertamos `'m'`, sabemos que es mayor que `'e'` y el bucle da una vuelta, en la siguiente vuelta sabemos que es mayor que `'i'` y damos otra vuelta, como se han acabado los elementos el punto de inserción es `2`.

#### Insertar.

Para insertar un valor en una posición de una formación, primero debes mover todos los elementos hacia adelante para dejar un hueco libre, esto expulsará de la formación el último elemento. Usando el puntero `c` del anterior punto y asumiendo que éste está en el punto de inserción:

```
memcpy(c + 1, c, fin - c - 2);
```

Fíjate que el último parámetro es la cantidad de elementos a copiar, le restamos dos porque queremos copiar un carácter menos y porque no queremos sobrescribir el carácter nulo de final de cadena, te pongo ejemplos con seis elementos:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 0 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
| e | i | o | u | v | x |\0 |
```

Si quisiera insertar en `0`:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |                      | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---| ===================> |---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
| e | i | o | u | v | x |\0 |                      | e | e | i | o | u | v |\0 |
  ^   ^                       ^
  c  c+1                      abecedario+vAbecedario
```

Si quisiera insertar en `3`:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |                      | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---| ===================> |---+---+---+---+---+---+---|
| e | i | o | u | v | x |\0 |                      | e | i | o | u | u | v |\0 |
              ^   ^           ^
              c  c+1          abecedario+vAbecedario
```

Una vez he movido los datos una posición, la posición `c` debe contener el nuevo elemento:

```
*c = dato;
```

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
char abecedario [] = {"aeiouvx"};
char *fin = abecedario + sizeof(abecedario);

char dato = 'z';

char *c = abecedario;
for (; dato > *c && c != fin; ++c);

if (c < fin)
{
    printf("Punto de insercion para '%c': %d\n", dato, c - abecedario);

    memcpy(c + 1, c, fin - c - 2);
    *c = dato;
    printf("Estado actual de abecedario: %s\n", abecedario);
}
else
    printf("'%c' se insertaria en una posicion fuera de la formacion.\n", dato);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDLUsIwFIbXyVMc60gLBUZdWmDn3r26OCYpZKZNOrkwCsOz15PKQHH75zv/JWKxFaLv77URTZQKVj5IbZe7DR9LTptt0rg2AVrUpthbLaf8yJnYoQP8UkJJdNrC@yes4Zih0jbuv7NTdUZmtTb0MiJL8PqgbF1ctWnFz7jEYAnPD/lFmombezKurYOi@mM36X0yAQF3a6CsCspSDH66hkLAKolTzqgy62hPqIvsLRq6pInaeOWEtgY6dAj5g8hf4EF@mGw@uM/JdgH/erJWtaL7Ie8SnoiYpwTCEvpMBGND43RfjUJffUBpAUWI2KTwqy1l@iHzJomdOFONVyOPVBD8uXcgDkEZiAahs14PQ@qoaAnZNwj0Ty0mdXlZNCxwKkRn4LHip77/BQ)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 0):

El código inserta el dato siempre y cuando no exista en el array, para probarlo deberás llenar el array manualmente ingresando letras al azar o si lo prefieres palabras, y luego el dato que se quiere insertar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//funcion que indica a 'qsort' que el ordenamiento es ascendente (a,b,c,d,e,....,z)
int comparar(const void *p, const void *q){
    char caracter1 = *(char*)p;
    char caracter2 = *(char*)q;

    if(caracter1 > caracter2) return 1;

    if(caracter1 < caracter2) return -1;

    return 0;
}

//inserta el dato en caso de que no exista y ordena las letras
void insertarCharOrdenado(char abecedario[], char dato){
    int i, insertar = 0, cantidad = strlen(abecedario);
    char aux[2];

    //encuentra si el dato a insertar ya existe o no
    for(i = 0; i < cantidad && !insertar; i++){
        if(abecedario[i] == dato){
            insertar = 1;
        }
    }

    //si el dato no existe es insertado en el array
    if(!insertar){
        aux[0] = dato;
        aux[1] = '\0';
        strcat(abecedario,aux);
        cantidad++;
    }

    //metodo de ordenamiento 'qsort' para ordenar el array 'abecedario'
    qsort(abecedario,cantidad,sizeof(char),comparar);
}

int main(void){
    char abecedario[50];
    char dato;

    printf("Ingrese letras al azar: ");
    scanf("%s",abecedario);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Ingrese letra a agregar: ");
    scanf("%c",&dato);
    fflush(stdin);

    insertarCharOrdenado(abecedario,dato);

    printf("resultado: %s",abecedario);

    return 0;
}
```